# Uploading image via AJAX and pass file name using Django form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, image-uploading

I am new in web development and what I am trying to achieve is as follows:

On a page where user create a blog

1. User upload image to a CDN via ajax and page will show image after
   ajax success.
2. The uploaded image to CDN has a new file name and obviously URL address but the filename in input type="file" remains to be the original file name. During form submission, the ajax-returned filename has to be submitted for server side processing.

I am not sure if I am doing it the right way as how I would normally observe on many websites. My question is, how do people normally sync filenames in above case when an Ajax upload is used and the file name has been changed and stored in CDN prior to a final form submission?

I am using Django but I guess that doesn't really make a huge difference.

Comment: This just sounds like something that should be in your app logic. So, you can return information from an AJAX call. Why not return the new URL/name of the uploaded file from the AJAX call, and your Javascript in the browser will then be able to load that URL however it wants.

Comment: Yes, I do return the URL/name via ajax call success. I am not sure how should I pass this returned information via form submission. So far I can think of creating a hidden input that bears the new filename. But this does not sound very safe as the input value can be altered and in django, the request.FILES["image"] might get something does not match the CDN filename.